# Matlab IIR filter

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

We were given a task to implement a filter(digital high pass IIR filter) to reduce frequencies below 500 Hz and allow higher frequencies. 
Using the sptool, and the ellip funciton we constructed the following

```
% Sampling Rate (Hz)
Fs = 46875; 

% High-pass filter
N = 4; % Filter Order
Wn = 500/(46875/2);  % Cutoff Frequency in terms of Passband / Nyquist frequency ratio
Rp = 0.5; % Passband ripple specification
Rs = 20; % Stopband attenuation

[Num,Den] = ellip(N,Rp,Rs,Wn,'high');

secondOrderSection = tf2sos(Num,Den)./2
```

We then calculated the scalefactors using L1 norm:
  We need to implement this on a 16 bit atmel microcontroller, (AC3U3 Xplained) and must    therefore calculate the scalefactors in Q_0.15 form

```
% FIRST SECTION
firstScaleFactor = 1/(sum(abs(impz(1,secondOrderSection(1,4:6)))))
sf1_2_Q = round(firstScaleFactor*(2^15))

% SECOND SECTION
secondScaleFactor = 1/(sum(abs(impz(1,secondOrderSection(2,4:6)))))
sf2_2_Q = round(secondScaleFactor*(2^15))
```

The Problem: Our scalefactors seems to be a bit low, First scale factor is 77, second is 14.
Is there any errors in our calculations?

Answer (score 1):

[This application note](http://spinlab.wpi.edu/courses/ece4703_2008/spra509.pdf) by Texas Instruments contains an overview of techniques for overflow avoidance in fixed-point filter implementation.